# Update random rows based on condition

Tags: sql-server

I have table with multiple columns and rows.
I want to update randomly 50 percent of the rows based on condition. 
Here is what I've tried but didn't work:

```
UPDATE dbo.tab1
SET column1 = 'A'
FROM dbo.tab1 as a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT TOP 50 percent *
FROM dbo.tab1
WHERE column2 NOT IN ('B','C','D')
ORDER BY NewID()
) as b 
on a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: Should this not start `UPDATE a`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, `column2` contains `NULL` values. Try to use the following

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(
  ID int,
  column1 varchar(1),
  column2 varchar(1)
)

INSERT tab1(ID,column1)VALUES
(1,'B'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'B'),
(4,'B'),
(5,'B'),
(6,'B')


UPDATE a
SET column1 = 'A'
FROM tab1 a
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT TOP 50 percent *
    FROM tab1
    --WHERE column2 NOT IN ('B','C','D')
    WHERE ISNULL(column2,'') NOT IN ('B','C','D')
    ORDER BY NewID()
  ) b 
ON a.ID = b.ID


SELECT *
FROM tab1
```

You also can try to use a query without `JOIN`

```
UPDATE q
SET column1 = 'A'
FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP 50 percent *
    FROM tab1
    --WHERE column2 NOT IN ('B','C','D')
    WHERE ISNULL(column2,'') NOT IN ('B','C','D')
    ORDER BY NewID()
  ) q
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a cte to make short work of this kind of thing. Something like this.

```
with MyUpdate as
(
    SELECT TOP 50 percent *
    FROM dbo.tab1
    WHERE column2 NOT IN ('B','C','D')
    ORDER BY NewID()
)

update MyUpdate
set column1 = 'A'
```